# Vue - Can not use or access this.$router or vue instance in my mixin file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuex

My src/mixins/chechauthMixin.js file is as follows:

```
export const checkauthMixin = {
    methods: {
        validateAuthentication: function(path) {
            if(this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
                this.$router.push('/dashboard')
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

However, it seems that the word 'this' is undefined here. I am calling this mixin method from a component or my routes.js file. How can I access the vue instance?
If this is not possible then what is a good workaround for such a scenario?

I have a similar mixin file where I store my social authentication function and that too uses 'this' instance. When I debug and try to use the instance in the console, it states that the element is undefined. However, my authentication code is able to work properly otherwise when I am not debugging.

What is going on in the two scenarios exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think I figured out the issue. I'm actually using a mixin incorrectly. The mixin is supposed to be used for multiple components that share a similar functionaliy. I was trying to use a mixin as a standalone function.

What I actually wanted to use was a routeguard. So the vue-router has a function called beforeach and that's what I wanted to use but didn't know about it when I faced this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because you're using the old javascript call

```
 validateAuthentication: function(path) {
        if(this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
            this.$router.push('/dashboard')
        }   
    }
```

Try using:

```
export const checkauthMixin = {
   methods: {
      validateAuthentication(path) {
          if(this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
             this.$router.push('/dashboard')
          }   
      }
   }
}
```

I also use mixins and I have no problem using this.$router... but I write my mixins with the newer syntax. Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help I appreciate this. So I used this approach and now 'this' is no longer undefined but it references the validateAuthentication method instead, So it seems that the vue instance that I have defined in main.js is still not accessible. so this.$store is still undefined and so is this.$router

Comment: @Hamza Please edit your question and show how you're trying to use the mixin. I might be able to help you. Are you importing the vuex in your component? And are your geeters ok?.. can you actually use your getters in the component that is using your mixin. I mean what hapens if you paste the code of your mixin directly in the component?

Comment: so apparently I figured out my issue. I am in fact not using a mixin correctly in this scenario. mixins are meant to be for components that share similar functions so I wanted to use a routeguard apparently which I just came across. Thank you so much for taking the time out and trying to help me. Highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If `this` isn't what you expect, try `self`:

```
validateAuthentication: function(path) {
    var self = this;
    if(self.$store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
        self.$router.push('/dashboard')
    }   
}
```

---

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time, try to make your code and question as succinct as possible. ["Walls of Text"](http://hananiahwilson.com/blog/dreaded-wall-of-text) (the sorta rambling paragraphs you have) make your question difficult to answer quickly, thus it will not be answered as quickly as it otherwise would have, or answered at all. Be conscientious that people on this site don't want to spend time understanding your question, so they will skip over it.

Also, be sure to add things you have tried, and what error you're getting. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you and apologies for the lengthy question. From what I understand, vue mixins are for reusable code primarily so I'm using this mixin method as a beforenter call in my routes file. It isn't connected to a component in this scenario. Is this not a good way to use mixins?

Comment: @Hamza You're using mixins exactly the right way. And I don't agree with Travis.. I think your question was precise and easy to understand